# element.click() doesn't work without alert()

Tags: javascript, setinterval, tampermonkey, getelementsbyclassname

I wrote a tampermokey script that counts the `i` intervals and clicks the next video, but the odd thing is it works only if the `alert` is uncommented:

```
var i = 1;
setInterval(function () {
   document.getElementsByClassName('PlaylistVideo')[i].click();
      // alert("i is equal to: "+ i); 
      i ++      
}, 5000);
```

Comment: it's a site you have to have an account for to use and I edited the class name to protect the site name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for some reason did it not like the \ alert

Answer (score 0):

Javascript has a zero-based array, so you should start you i with 0;

```
var i = 0;
```

Comment: when i did that at first it was playing the 1st video 2 times.  It seem that the getElementsByClassName is counting 4 videos 1-4

Comment: Can you tell me how to reset i back to nothing for the next run (when I move a diffrent page it stops working even though the URL is included in the @match section of the script)